# Dataproc cluster creation fail with kerberos option

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to create dataproc cluster with kerberos option, but cluster creation is failing.

I am following the below steps, which are listed in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/security#gcloud-create-kerberos-cluster).

and creating the cluster from gcloud. After creating the key, keyring and encryption password file:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster-name \  
    --image-version=1.3 \  
    --kerberos-root-principal-password-uri=gs://my-bucket/kerberos-root-principal-password.encrypted \  
    --kerberos-kms-key=projects/project-id/locations/global/keyRings/my-keyring/cryptoKeys/my-key
```

But after 3-4 min for cluster creation, it fails. Error in master/worker node logs:

```
<13>Apr 15 17:26:22 google-dataproc-startup[782]: + echo 'Creating service principals on cluster-dataproc-kerberos-22-m.c.xxxxxxxxxx.internal'
<13>Apr 15 17:26:22 google-dataproc-startup[782]: Creating service principals on cluster-dataproc-kerberos-22-m.c.xxxxxxxxxx.internal
<13>Apr 15 17:26:22 google-dataproc-startup[782]: + set +x
<13>Apr 15 17:26:22 google-dataproc-startup[782]: kadmin: Preauthentication failed while initializing kadmin interface
<13>Apr 15 17:26:22 google-dataproc-startup[782]: Authenticating as principal root with password.
<13>Apr 15 17:26:23 google-dataproc-startup[782]: kadmin: Preauthentication failed while initializing kadmin interface
<13>Apr 15 17:26:23 google-dataproc-startup[782]: Authenticating as principal root with password.
```

Am I doing anything wrong or need to configure anything else?

Comment: Did you check the log `/var/log/auth.log`? This might give you more details.

Comment: Also, do you have any special characters in your password? For example, spaces, tabs, quotation marks?

Comment: Getting below error msgs on master node /var/log/auth.log

Comment: Apr 19 09:50:13 dataproc-kerberos-m krb5kdc[1585]: preauth (encrypted_timestamp) verify failure: Preauthentication failed
Apr 19 09:50:13 dataproc-kerberos-m krb5kdc[1585]: AS_REQ (8 etypes {18 17 20 19 16 23 25 26}) 10.253.59.3: PREAUTH_FAILED: root@C.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.INTERNAL for kadmin/dataproc-kerberos-m.c.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.internal@C.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.INTERNAL,

Comment: Apr 19 10:00:21 dataproc-kerberos-m krb5kdc[1585]: AS_REQ (8 etypes {18 17 20 19 16 23 25 26}) 10.253.59.5: CLIENT_NOT_FOUND: dataproc/dataproc-kerberos-m.c.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.internal@C.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.INTERNAL for krbtgt/C.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.INTERNAL@C.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.INTERNAL, Client not found in Kerberos database

Comment: The second error message "CLIENT_NOT_FOUND" is just a symptom because principal root@C.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.INTERNAL was not created and cannot be used to create other principals. "kadmin: Preauthentication failed while initializing kadmin interface" usually suggests the password is incorrect. Do you mind sharing the password you encrypted in "gs://my-bucket/kerberos-root-principal-password.encrypted"

Comment: Thanks for update.
Here is  Asfglkjlif23sd12

Comment: I tried to use the same password and it worked for me. Is the failure consistent for you?

Comment: Thanks...Yes.. Its consistent.. Tried multiple times, but its failing with same error.

Comment: If if the cluster creation failed, the VM nodes will still be there. Can you ssh to the master then try `kinit root`, or `kadmin -p root -w Asfglkjlif23sd12 -q "listprincs"`?

Comment: Thanks for reply.

username@cluster-dataproc-test-m:~$ kadmin -p root -w Asfglkjlif23sd12 -q "listprincs"
Authenticating as principal root with password.
kadmin: Preauthentication failed while initializing kadmin interface

username@cluster-dataproc-test-m:~$ kinit root
Password for root@C.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.INTERNAL: 
kinit: Password incorrect while getting initial credentials
username@cluster-dataproc-test-m:~$